# Null Functions & Fixing SQL Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, null

I'm suppose to correct this statement and show the Annual Salary and replace the nulls with a 0.

How would I go about doing it?

```
SELECT last_name, salary, commission_pct,
salary * .0333 + commission_pct Bonus_Calc
FROM employees;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this homework?

Read about the `COALESCE` function: (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions023.htm#i1001341).

Answer (score 1):

The standard SQL function to do this is `coalesce`.
Assuming that first name, last name and salary can't be `null`:

```
SELECT last_name, salary, COALESCE(commission_pct, 0),
       salary * .0333 + COALESCE(commission_pct, 0) Bonus_Calc
FROM   employees;
```

Alternatively, in Oracle, you can also use `NVL`:

```
SELECT last_name, salary, NVL(commission_pct, 0),
       salary * .0333 + NVL(commission_pct, 0) Bonus_Calc
FROM   employees;
```

Comment: These both worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What `NULL` values are you trying to replace with a 0?  Assuming that every employee has a non-NULL salary but that the `commission_pct` may be `NULL`, you can replace a `NULL` commission_pct with a 0 using the `NVL` function

```
NVL( commission_pct, 0 )
```

As for correcting the calculation, it's not obvious what you're asking. It makes no sense to add a commission percentage to a salary.  You'd generally need something (like total volume of sales) to multiply the commission percentage by in order to get at a dollar amount that can be added to the salary.  I'm also confused as to how multiplying the salary by 0.0333 makes sense.  I'm hard-pressed to envision what 1/30 of the `salary` represents.

Comment: This was given to me in class, there is nothing I can do to change it.